# use RecyclerView and CardView and set app to run in earlier versions than Lollipop

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

As you know, Android Lollipop features two new widgets to make your life easier, RecyclerView and CardView...I wanna use these two features in my app, but how does my app run in eralier android versions?( for example in JellyBean)
how can I set my app resource files to run in all kind of android versions? if I use  v7 Support Library, can I use the RecyclerView and CardView widgets on devices that run older versions of Android?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecyclerView and CardView is part of the v7 support library which means you can use it on anything that has api 7 and up.

As described in the official [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html)

Each Support Library is backward-compatible to a specific Android API level.

For example the

```
support v4 : minSdk=4
v7 appcompat library: minSdk=7
v7 recyclerview library: minSdk = 7
v7 CardView library: minSdk = 7
```